# Property does not exist for medium screen

Tags: html, css, properties, size

I cannot really believe I've sat down with this for over 2 hours now, why I come here begging for some answers. Why do not this code validate? It is the exact same code found on the interwebs, and I seem to be the only one getting this validation message.

Message I'm getting:

> Egenskap -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio finns inte för medium screen ) { p.hej { > color: blue; } }
>   25        Egenskap -ms-high-contrast finns inte för medium all ), (-ms-high-> contrast: none) { p.hej { color: green; } }

And two warnings

> ### can't find the warning message for vendor-ext-pseudo-class
>
> 32        can't find the warning message for vendor-ext-pseudo-class ##

I can't understand why.

What I'm trying to do is a simple HTML file that is, by CSS, adjusted individually with these variables:

Firefox: -moz-
Chrome och Safari: -webkit-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
Opera: -o-

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Min fantastiska uppgift 2.8</title>
<link href="sajt3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<p class="hej">Hej!!!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* 
Firefox targeting, red h1 text color
 */

body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) p.hej {
    color:red;
  }


/* 
Chrome & Safari targeting, blue h1 text color
 */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   p.hej { color: blue; } 
}



/* 
IE targeting, green H1 text color
 */

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   p.hej { color: green; } 
}


 /* 
Opera targeting; purple bg
 */

x:-o-prefocus, p {
  background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works if you change the first bit of your css to

```
body:not(.hej) {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.hej{color:blue;}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbu9jyak/2/)

I don't think it likes ids and class names together!